# How to resolve my database connection error when using the Wordpress Migrate module?

Tags: 8, database, migrations

I have a Drupal8 site and I've installed the [Wordpress Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/wordpress_migrate) module and it's dependencies for migrating a Wordpress site to Drupal8.

When I start to import the exported XML file from Wordpress, I get this error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

When I checked the error messages pages I found this:

> Drupal\Core\Database\ConnectionNotDefinedException: The specified database connection is not defined: migrate in Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection() (line 361 of /media/mosama/Content/test_poc/drupal8_2/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php).

Any solution for this?

Comment: One related issue queue for this matter is here https://www.drupal.org/node/2839482

Answer (score 6):

Solved!
By adding anothe data base configuration with ['migrate'] in **settings.php** under the default database like this

```
$databases['migrate']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'NAME',
  'username' => 'USER',
  'password' => 'PASS',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```